# JPA save validation error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, relational-database, bean-validation

I have these entities:

- GrandFather
- Father
- Child

Their relations are:
GrandFather - [hasMany] - Father - [hasMany] - Child.

*Father* has *@NotEmpty* validation on *child* field:

```
@NotEmpty
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Child> children;
```

When I have a brand new and connected entities(GrandFather, Father, Child) everything works perfect. But if GrandFather was already saved and fetched from DB, then new Father and Child (through Father) added to GrandFather causes *ConstraintViolationException*:

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=children, rootBeanClass=class com.example.models.Father, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
```

If no validation is specified it works and saves to DB, also it works when Father was saved before added to GrandFather. Research showed that at the stage of validation Father object has null in its *children* property(possibly because Child was not saved and does not have ID), but it has *grandFather* property set.

How can I achieve both saving and validation without saving Child and Parent entities first?

```
@Test
public void contextLoads() {
    grandFatherRepository.deleteAll();
    GrandFather grandFather = (GrandFather)((grandFatherRepository.findAll().toArray().length == 0) ? null : grandFatherRepository.findAll().toArray()[0]);
    if (grandFather == null) {
        grandFather = grandFatherRepository.save(new GrandFather());
    }

    Father father = new Father();
    grandFather.addFather(father);

    Child child = new Child();
    father.addChild(child);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(grandFather);
    System.out.print(constraintViolations); // prints null

    grandFatherRepository.save(grandFather); // Crashes here
}




@Entity
public class GrandFather extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grandFather", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Father> fathers;

    public GrandFather() {}

    public Set<Father> getFathers() {
        return fathers;
    }

    public void setFathers(Set<Father> fathers) {
        this.fathers = fathers;
    }

    public void addFather(Father father) {
        if (father == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (fathers == null) {
            fathers = new HashSet<>();
        }
        father.setGrandFather(this);
        fathers.add(father);
    }
}




    @Entity
public class Father extends BaseEntity {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private GrandFather grandFather;

    @NotEmpty
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public Father() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GrandFather getGrandFather() {
        return grandFather;
    }

    public void setGrandFather(GrandFather grandFather) {
        this.grandFather = grandFather;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        if (child == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (children == null) {
            children = new HashSet<>();
        }
        child.setFather(this);
        children.add(child);
    }
}




@Entity
public class Child extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Father father;

    public Child() {
    }

    public Father getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(Father father) {
        this.father = father;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show relationships of your other entities as well? I am assuming you are not doing bidirectional relationship here, but you are adding the objects on the non-owner side.

Comment: @Vaelyr updated code

Comment: Because you are using bidirectional relationships, I believe you have to always save the father explicitly before grandFather in case where it already existed. It would be recommended to always do that anyway.